# Problem with tikz macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to optimize my latex code used for drawings (i.e. make it easier to read/update after 1 week) and therefore I'm trying to use some macros for this. Now, I know the following example is stupid, but could you give me a hand - I really don't get it, why I can't draw some square using my macro.

So basically, I want to use something like this

```
\newcommand*\myPatternsB{
\squareNVSE{0.00}{77.99}
\squareNVSE{6.01}{77.99}
\squareNVSE{12.02}{77.99}
}
```

instead of this

```
\newcommand*\myPatternsA{
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] (  0.00mm,  77.99mm) -| (  6.00mm, 71.99mm) -| (  0.00mm,  77.99mm);
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] (  6.01mm,  77.99mm) -| ( 12.01mm, 71.99mm) -| (  6.01mm,  77.99mm);
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] ( 12.02mm,  77.99mm) -| ( 18.02mm, 71.99mm) -| ( 12.02mm,  77.99mm);
}
```

The square macro looks like this

```
\newcommand*\squareNVSE[2]{
\draw [draw=gray, very thin]
    ( #1 mm,  #2 mm)
 -| ( #1 + 6.00mm, #2 - 6.00mm)
 -| ( #1 mm,  #2 mm);

% what I want this macro/function to do
%\draw [draw=gray, very thin]
%    (  0.00mm, 77.99mm)
% -| (  6.00mm, 71.99mm)
% -| (  0.00mm, 77.99mm);
}
```

I'm using the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\squareNVSE[2]{
\draw [draw=gray, very thin]
    ( #1 mm,  #2 mm)
 -| ( #1 + 6.00mm, #2 - 6.00mm)
 -| ( #1 mm,  #2 mm);

% what I want this macro/function to do
%\draw [draw=gray, very thin]
%    (  0.00mm, 77.99mm)
% -| (  6.00mm, 71.99mm)
% -| (  0.00mm, 77.99mm);
}
\newcommand*\drawing{
  \draw ( 12.10mm,  81.39mm)   %a8
     -- (  1.50mm,  81.39mm)   %a9 
     -- (  1.50mm,  77.99mm)   %a10
     -- (  0.00mm,  77.99mm);  %a11
\node [anchor=north]      at ( 12.10mm,  81.39mm) {\tiny a8};
\node [anchor=south]      at (  1.50mm,  81.39mm) {\tiny a9};
\node [anchor=south west] at (  1.50mm,  77.99mm) {\tiny a10};
\node [anchor=south]      at (  0.00mm,  77.99mm) {\tiny a11};
}


\newcommand*\myPatternsA{
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] (  0.00mm,  77.99mm) -| (  6.00mm, 71.99mm) -| (  0.00mm,  77.99mm);
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] (  6.01mm,  77.99mm) -| ( 12.01mm, 71.99mm) -| (  6.01mm,  77.99mm);
\draw [draw=gray, very thin] ( 12.02mm,  77.99mm) -| ( 18.02mm, 71.99mm) -| ( 12.02mm,  77.99mm);
}
\newcommand*\myPatternsB{
\squareNVSE{0.00}{77.99}
\squareNVSE{6.01}{77.99}
\squareNVSE{12.02}{77.99}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2, yscale=2]
    \myPatternsA
    \drawing
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[tH]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2, yscale=2]
    \myPatternsB
    \drawing
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I'm using "pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.8.25)" - I know it is kind of old, but still...

I'm using notepad++ to execute the followings

```
npp_save
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$(FILE_NAME)"
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && makeindex "$(FILE_NAME)".idx
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$(FILE_NAME)"
cmd /c cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && pdflatex.exe -shell-escape "$(FILE_NAME)"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).pdf"
```

This is the output I get - I would like squares for the second graph, but something is really wrong and I don't understand what.
[image: the output on my machine]

Comment: I'm including other packages too, but this is the minimum working example on which I get this thing.

Comment: It appears that you only forgot some units: `\draw [draw=gray, very thin]
    ( #1 mm,  #2 mm)
 -| ( #1 mm + 6.00mm, #2 mm - 6.00mm)
 -| ( #1 mm,  #2 mm);`

Comment: Thank you @Lazy squirrel. This fixes my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(for the question being marked "solved", i.e. having an accepted answer)

As [Lazy squirrel pointed out in comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574636/problem-with-tikz-macro#comment1447228_574636), in `( #1 + 6.00mm, #2 - 6.00mm)` you forgot two units `mm`, which makes the default unit `cm` applied, and finally makes the drawing much higher than expected.

Comment: thank you all. This fixes my issue